# How to install Jenkins Ubuntu slave as a service?

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine where I am successfully connected to the Jenkins server via JNLP connection. Steps I took for the connection are the following:

1. Create a directory in the slave called /home/MyUbuntu/Jenkins
2. Download both agent.jar and slave-agent.jnlp files into the
   directory
3. Run this command from the terminal:

java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://my-jenkins-server:8080/computer/MyNode/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 6f8bb3250d6dbcda77979797997b0ea6bcaaa064785d558c0e4ea07d03 -workDir "/home/MyUbuntu/Jenkins"

The connection is successful.

**Problem:** 
Once I close the terminal the connection gets disconnected.

**Question:**
How do I add this as a service in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS so whenever the machine is rebooted it starts as a startup???

Comment: you can start your process when your system boots up, put it on your cron jobs, that would be the easiest way

Comment: How do I make it so it runs all time, I dont want it to be any time specific.

Comment: It's not for Ubuntu, but [this page](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/207849467-CentOS-JNLP-startup-script) at least has [Startup scripts for CentOS](https://gist.github.com/christ66/fae63fefd2b8237300cd2cac0e0dfe43).

Comment: try this one https://arjunphp.com/jenkins-agent-linux-service/

Answer (score 2):

If you use System D, add a file like this to `/etc/systemd/system/`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Jenkins slave connection
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkinsurl:port/endpoint.jnlp -secret 4lph4num3r1cs3cr3t -workDir "/base/path/of/your/jenkinsjar"
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/base/path/of/your/jenkinsjar
User=my-user
Group=my-group
RestartSec=20s


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=jenkins.service
```

Permissions and ownership of the file may vary based on the service or OS. Long list files in `/lib/systemd/system/` to get an idea of what perms you need or want (probably `root:root 644`).

Notice the command is the command that Jenkins provides for you when you create an agent jar. Just use that for `ExecStart`.

For `user` and `group`, I use the user that owns the directory where the Jenkins workspace is located. For example, if the Jenkins workspace is in `/home/ubuntu`, I specify `ubuntu` as `user` and `group`.

After that...

**Prefix these with** `sudo` **if you're not running as root**:

Probably a good idea to reload System D: `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Start: `systemctl start jenkins.service`. Notice this command pertains to the last line of the file `Alias`.

Enable it if you want the service to start with your computer: `systemctl enable jenkins.service`.

*Here are the Git Gists I based my file on:*

https://gist.github.com/unakatsuo/d4711f52a0ab0b9bc8010018149a7e84
https://gist.github.com/dragolabs/05dfe1c0899221ce51204dbfe7feecbb

I'm sure there's a lot more that can be done for the service config but in my case, I manage a lot of different servers and just need the thing to start automatically after boot!